# R Using ggplot with a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I have a list of dataframes (df_list) which I want to plot with ggplot. I want to display the Date on the x-scale (its always the same of course) and then 2 different geo_lines. The first geoline out of the df1-3 and the 2nd line from abc. Here is an examle code:

```
library(lubridate)
v1 = seq(ymd('2000-05-01'),ymd('2000-05-10'),by='day')
v2 = seq(2,20, length = 10)
v3 = seq(-2,7, length = 10)
v4 = seq(-6,3, length = 10)
df1 = data.frame(Date = v1, df1_Tmax = v2, df1_Tmean = v3, df1_Tmin = v4)

v1 = seq(ymd('2000-05-01'),ymd('2000-05-10'),by='day')
v2 = seq(3,21, length = 10)
v3 = seq(-3,8, length = 10)
v4 = seq(-7,4, length = 10)
df2 = data.frame(Date = v1, df2_Tmax = v2, df2_Tmean = v3, df2_Tmin = v4)

v1 = seq(ymd('2000-05-01'),ymd('2000-05-10'),by='day')
v2 = seq(4,22, length = 10)
v3 = seq(-4,9, length = 10)
v4 = seq(-8,5, length = 10)
df3 = data.frame(Date = v1, df3_Tmax = v2, df3_Tmean = v3, df3_Tmin = v4)

v1 = seq(ymd('2000-05-01'),ymd('2000-05-10'),by='day')
v2 = seq(2,20, length = 10)
v3 = seq(-2,8, length = 10)
v4 = seq(-6,3, length = 10)
abc = data.frame(Date = v1, ABC_Tmax = v2, ABC_Tmean = v3, ABC_Tmin = v4)

df_list = list(df1, df2, df3, abc)
names(df_list) = c("df1", "df2", "df3", "abc")
```

For example I want to plot `df_list$df1$df1_Tmax` together with `df_list$abc$ABC_Tmax`.

I tried this:

```
ggplot(data = df_list, aes(x = df1$Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = df1$df1_Tmax), color = "darkgreen", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = abc$ABC_Tmax), color = "grey27", size = 1) +
  labs(title="Title", 
       subtitle="subtitle", 
       x = "day", 
       y = "T") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%d",date_breaks  ="1 day")
```

But I get this error message:

```
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a list
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use `map` or `walk`.  Make sure the names are common in all the list elements

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to use that. What do you mean? Can you please give me an example on my code?

Comment: SInce you wanted only two lines, probably, bind the datsetss df1 to df3 together after changing the column names to a common one?

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of stuff to plot. So binding all the matching dataframes together will take forever. So I am searching a solution for the list of dataframes.

Comment: okay, the question is unclear .  ggplot wouldn't work with list

Comment: Oh ok, so there is no way to make ggplot with with lists?

Comment: Yes, given that ggplot doesn't deal with list, why not create a new data frame by binding two columns from these two data frames.

Comment: Ok thanks! I did not know that ggplot doesnt work with it because it works when I stay within one entry of the list.

Comment: @Essi One entry of the list is a data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = cbind(df_list$df1, df_list$abc), aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = df1_Tmax), color = "darkgreen", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y = ABC_Tmax), color = "grey27", size = 1) +
  labs(title="Title", 
       subtitle="subtitle", 
       x = "day", 
       y = "T") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%d",date_breaks  ="1 day")
```

Just generate a new data frame using `cbind`, i.e., `cbind(df_list$df1, df_list$abc)` within `ggplot` function.

Caution:
`cbind(df_list$df1, df_list$abc)` leads to the following error.

> Error: `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate columns

Please try this since you also have the same `Date` variable in these two data frames.

Comment: BTW, why don't you merge all these columns into one data frame since you have same Date variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I know, it would be easier. I wanted to experiement with list of dataframes.